# Improve performance of Image when there are multiple

Tags: react-native

#### Problem

I'm rendering multiple images (3-4) horizontally picked from gallery using `react-native-image-picker`. And putting them to `<Image />` using base64 string. But after picking third photo, UI is not responding correctly and lagging so much. My android device has 4GB ram.

How can I improve this?

#### Reproducible Demo

```react
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
         Photos: [null, null, null]
    }

    this.renderPhotosView = this.renderPhotosView.bind(this)
    this.onPhotoSelect = this.onPhotoSelect.bind(this)
}

renderPhotosView() {

    var self = this
    var Photos = self.state.Photos

    return (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}} >
            {
                Photos.map(function (photoBase64Data, i) {

                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            key={i}
                            onPress={() => {

                                ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {

                                    if (response.didCancel) {
                                        return
                                    }

                                    self.onPhotoSelect(i,  response.data)
                                })
                            }}
                            style={{
                                flex:  30,
                                backgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                                height: 100,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                margin: 5
                            }}
                        >
                            <View>
                                {
                                    (photoBase64Data == null) ?
                                    <Icon name="ios-add" /> :
                                    <Image

                                        source={{ uri: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + photoBase64Data }}
                                        style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
                                    />
                                }
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                })
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have solved it by resizing the picked images with `react-native-image-resizer`.

Example:

```
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
    if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };

        ImageResizer.createResizedImage(source.uri, 600, 600, 'JPEG', 50, 0, null).then((resizedImageUri) => {

            // use resized image 
            this.newImage(resizedImageUri);
        }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(`error at resizing image: ${err}`);
        });
    }
    });
```

Comment: This is an option but I wonder if react-native provides a way without third party libs.